# Why ReactJS render data values in charts only on localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I created Restful API on node.js and EXPRESS.

When other users try to see data in JSON with my local ip address everythink is fine.

When other users try to open my ReactAPP with my local ip address  the charts is empty.

When I open my ReactAPP the charts is full with data values ?

May be I have error in render or ... I dont know ...

My Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from "react-dropdown-select";
//import Calendar from 'react-calendar';


import './aladin.css';
import {
    ComposedChart,
    Bar,
    BarChart,
    Area,
    Line,
    XAxis,
    YAxis,
    CartesianGrid,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from 'recharts';

class Aladin extends React.Component {


    state = {
        date: new Date(),
    }

    onChange = date => this.setState({ date })

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            dataAPI: null,
            temp: null,
            dats: null,
        };
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=2";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ dataAPI: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
        this.setState({ temp: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
        this.setState({ dats: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
        //console.log(this.state.temp[1].TA);
        //console.log(this.state.dats[1].DATS);
        //console.log(this.state.date);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="grid-container-aladin">

                <div className="grid-all-items">

                    <div className="header-aladin">
                        <div className="select">

                            <Select />
                            <Select />
                        </div>
                        <p><b>TA - Температура с данни на 3 часа, RH - Влажност на въздуха с данни от 3 часа, WS - Скорост на вятъра с данни от 3 часа.</b></p>
                        <p><b>SR - Сняг с данни на 3 часа, RR - Дъжд с данни от 3 часа, DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя.</b></p>
                        <ComposedChart width={800} height={400} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                            top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                        }}>
                            <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='TA' fill='#f56200' stroke='#f56200' />
                            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="RH" stroke="#8884d8" />
                            <Bar dataKey='WS' barSize={20} fill='#00ff0d' />
                            <Bar dataKey='SR' barSize={20} fill='#f70000' />
                            <Bar dataKey='RR' barSize={20} fill='#003cff' />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#000000" />
                        </ComposedChart>
                    </div>



                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> ТА - Температура с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <BarChart
                            width={800}
                            height={400}
                            data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Bar dataKey="TA" stackId="a" fill="#f56200" />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </BarChart>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> WS - Скорост на вятъра с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <BarChart
                            width={800}
                            height={400}
                            data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Bar dataKey="WS" stackId="a" fill="#f56200" />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </BarChart>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> RH - Влажност на въздуха с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <ComposedChart width={800} height={400} data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='RH' fill='#8884d8' stroke='#8884d8' />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </ComposedChart>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> APRESS - Атм. налягане с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <ComposedChart width={800} height={400} data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                            <Area type='monotone' dataKey='APRES' fill='#8884d8' stroke='#8884d8' />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </ComposedChart>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> RR - Валеж с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <BarChart
                            width={800}
                            height={400}
                            data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Bar dataKey="RR" stackId="a" fill="#4287f5" />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </BarChart>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid-item-aladin">
                        <p><b> SR - Сняг с данни на 3 часа:<br />DATS - Дата избрана от потребителя:</b></p>
                        <BarChart
                            width={800}
                            height={400}
                            data={this.state.dats}
                            margin={{
                                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
                            }}
                        >
                            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                            <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                            <YAxis />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            <Bar dataKey="SR" stackId="a" fill="#4287f5" />
                            <Bar dataKey="DATS" stackId="a" fill="#303030" />
                        </BarChart>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default Aladin;
```

**I don't think the error is in the API because users see the data in JSON format.**

I'm also uploading my API code on node.js and EXPRESS:

The code:

```
// Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')
var express = require("express")
var cors = require('cors')


app.use(cors())


// Server port
var HTTP_PORT = 8000

// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%",HTTP_PORT))
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "192.168.1.1",
  port: "1456",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass"
});

let aladinModel='';


/*
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //Select all customers and return the result object:

    con.query("CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram('2018-08-01',41027,5)", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      aladinModel = result;
    });
});
*/


// Root endpoint
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const date = req.query.date;
  const station = req.query.station;
  const daysForward = req.query.daysForward;

  try {
    const query = `CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram('${date}', ${station}, ${daysForward})`;
    con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      aladinModel = result;
    });
    res.json({aladinModel})
  } catch(error){
    console.log("Error query database!!!");
  } 

});


app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they can't see data because when they access your app using your IP address, they access the UI. But since you mentioned `localhost:8000` in your code, and because the UI code is executed from their browser, they will try to fetch data with this IP address (locahost == 127.0.0.1) and not yours.

The value of you `const url` variable should be relative to the IP address the client is accessing and using.

First, you can try this:

```
const url = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=2";
```

Maybe the other users will encounter CORS problems after this change:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own.
>
> — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

If this happens, you could configure your backend to accept CORS requests.

Comment: I update my question.
Can you give me example with this const ? Where can I put this part of the code ?

Comment: Well, you have in your react code already this constant. In the `async componentDidMount` method. You just have to change its value with my example and test it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Paul Rey
window.location.hostname give path name and it would be better with IP address of host. It is a local network.

Like:

```
const url = "http://" + 192.168.1.XXX + ":8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=2";
```

Comment: Where can I put this const ?
Can you give me example please..

Comment: I agree for the test, but if the OP wants to publish its app, he would use the hostname and not the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users too, you have hard coded localhost in component & obviously there is no service available on end-user machine.

Try replacing localhost with your ip in url

```
const url = "http://localhost:8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=2";
```

You have hardcoded that in the `componentDidMount` method

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://<Ip here>:8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=2";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();
```

Comment: Work perfect.. everywhere from every PC :D 

Thank you guys..